# JAXB adding enum as flat structure

Tags: java, enums, jaxb, annotations

How could I get a plain JSON structure like this

```
{
    "id": 9901,
    "name": "Reader",
    "value": true
}
```

with JAXB annotations and that code? (UserInfo should contain enum fields in the same hierarchy level)

```
@XmlRootElement
public class UserInfo
{
    private UserLevel level;

    @XmlElement ( name = "value" )
    private boolean allowed;
}

public enum UserLevel
{
    READER ( "Reader", 9901 ),
    TESTER ( "Tester", 9903 );

    private final String name;
    private final int id;

    private UserLevel( String name, int id )
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.id = id;
    }

    get...()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to have another JAXB class that matches your desired JSON structure, something like this (constructor missing):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class UserInfoFlattened
{
    @XmlElement
    private int id;

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElement ( name = "value" )
    private boolean allowed;
}
```

Then you should use an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on class `UserInfo`, which looks about like this:

```
public class UserInfoAdapter extends XmlAdapter<UserInfoFlattened, UserInfo>
{
    @Override
    public UserInfoFlattened marshal( UserInfo userInfo )
    {
        return new UserInfoFlattened( userInfo.getValue(), userInfo.getUserLevel().getId(), userInfo.getUserLevel().getName() );
    }

    // unmarshal analogous
}
```